How to add file attachment to email in smptlib?
I've made an email sending script, but I don't know how to send a file with it. Help!
filename = 'image.png'
my_user = 'myemail@gmail.com'  # 
my_pass = 'my app code' 

smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.login(my_user, my_pass)

sent_from = my_user
sent_to = 'myotheremail'  #  Send it to self (as test)
email_text = 'This is a test'
smtpserver.sendmail(sent_from, sent_to, email_text, filename)

smtpserver.close()

